# Add attributes to class from list

Tags: python, list, class, object

I have a list in a .txt file that includes data about cars. The list is like this:

```
Audi;2002;2500  
Peugeot;1967;2040  
Mercedes;2020;12000
```

etc., there is 10 items in total.

I need to somehow use a class with brand, model and price as the attributes and make a list out of these. So a list of 10 elements with `Audi 2002 2500` as the first line, `Peugeot 1967 2040` as second line, etc.

I have gotten this far:

```py
file = open("doc.txt", "r")

class CAR():
   brand = ""
   model = 0
   price = 0      

def readdoc(file, listA)
   lines = 0
   for line in file:
     lines = lines + 1
     listA.append(line.strip())
```

This function gives me the file in a list format `['Audi;2002;2500, '...']`.

But then I get lost on what to do. I am supposed to "combine" the list and the class `CAR` somehow to make a list where the first line is `Audi 2002 2500` and then I would need to do some simple calculations with the price and model (for example multiplication).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't apologize; learn. You can start by reading [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each line you may split on `;` and build the `CAR` instance with the 3 values

```
class CAR:
    brand: str
    year: int
    price: int

    def __init__(self, brand, year, price):
        self.brand = brand
        self.year = year
        self.price = price


def readdoc(file):
    result = []
    with open(file, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            br, ye, pr = line.strip().split(";")
            result.append(CAR(br, int(ye), int(pr)))
    return result


cars = readdoc("doc.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have also read that the def init thingy would/could work but I am trying to solve a problem that is part of a course that I am attending and we have not been taught the def init part yet, so I feel like we are not supposed to use it. Are there any alternatives to this solution?

Comment: @PythoNoob If you need to save with class instances yes you need that. If not you'll do `result.append(line.strip().split(";"))` and you'll only have a list of lists

Comment: @PythoNoob you could use `dataclasses` but I guess that you haven't been taught either (and I am not sure if it doesn't implement that under the hood (tho it says something about that being optional (but I am a bit confused there, either how, you wouldn't have to write the method yourself)))

Comment: @azro The class part is confusing to me, cause I also thought that it would be easier to just create a list of lists and then use their indexes to make the calculations and stuff.

Comment: @PythoNoob what calculations do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Matiiss We have been taught only the pretty basic stuff (basic operations like print, input etc, working with files and lists, basics of libraries and other basics), which is kinda problematic at time cause I am not sure what I am even looking for (like in this situation)

Comment: @PythoNoob You said you need to use a class though, so I'm a little confused

Comment: @Matiis I would need to multiply (and also divide)  the cars model and price with each other, and put the results to a list.

Comment: @Bharel I am also extremely confused and have spent a good amount of hours trying to solve the problem at hand. I just don't get how/why we are supposed to use the class, when just normal lists should do the job just fine. But it's an assignment that's going to be graded so I want to do as I have been told.

Comment: @PythoNoob well if you had a list of theses classes you could easily just add their attributes together, for example here would be your list (see answer) and you for example wanted the sum of the prices of the cars, you could do sth like `total_price = sum(car.price for car in cars)`

Comment: @PythoNoob well, classes are individual, that is why they are easier to later use, for example you can define individual methods that will rely on instance attributes, instead of you having to write some function that will rely on list indexes and will overall be less readable (similarly with a dictionary) and really, classes are just different looking dictionaries, they are just easier (when you understand them) and more individual than having some other data structure

Comment: @Matiiss but my main problem is how do I get the attributes to class from the list. It would have to be some kind of loop that goes through the list and adds the [0] element to brand, [1] to year and [2] to price and does the same for all 10 elements on the list. And the results should be stored as a list also.

Comment: @Matiiss I will try to get myself more familiar with classes. But this task is supposed to be done with the veery limited class knowledge which has been taught to us thus far :/

Comment: @PythoNoob that is already shown in the answer, also you can use value unpacking instead of indexes (also see the answer)

Comment: @Matiiss can the answer be implemented without the def __init__ part?

Comment: @PythoNoob if you need individual classes, then no, one class, then you could have the class attributes to be lists and append to those and then use `zip`, but seemingly you need individual instances so you have to use `__init__`

Comment: @Matiiss He doesn't need `__init__`, he can just assign the attributes later on. Might not be a great thing, but can work I guess

Comment: Ok a small status update. I managed to split the list at ; and now it prints to separate lines. Now I need to add the brand, model and price as class attributes and add that to another list

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Bharel you can also assign instance attributes without the `__init__` method, not how it is usually done (AFAIK), but basically it is the same thing:

```py
class Car:
    brand: str = ''
    year: int = 0
    price: int = 0


def readfile(file):
    result = []
    with open(file, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            brand, year, price = line.strip().split(";")
            car = Car()
            car.brand = brand
            car.year = year
            car.price = price
            result.append(car)
    return result


cars = readfile("doc.txt")
```